# Openlayers 4+ using local vector tiles (.pbf) without server

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers, local, tiles

I'm new in online mapping, and in the past I've created raster maps succesfully with Maperitive from osm data. It works fine from localhost/ local folder structure.  But my question: Is it possible to serve local vector maps from .pbf or geojson files without any server or mapbox stuff just like raster images? Is it possible to render without any server or api key required service in the browser directly in the client side? 
If yes, could someone provide me a working example?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you want to create an html page (with a map on it) that you open directly from your computer's hard drive?

Comment: Hmm.. your question sounds simply, but yes. Based on vector tiles. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally websites cannot access your local file system. This is to protect you and your computer from websites spying on you.

However, there are exceptions to that rule.

1. Websites can read files that you selected in a "upload file" input element.
2. A page can read file system, when it is opended from the disk

Opening an html document from the harddrive means that you simply double click it on your computer and the browser opens it. All relative links in that html document are then relative to that document.

So if you use the [GeoJSON class](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html), you can simply give it a path to files on your computer. Here is an example that reads a local file named `mygeojson.geojson` from a folder `mysubfolder` and shows it on top of a OpenStreetMap layer:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: 'mysubfolder/mygeojson.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#319FD3',
            width: 1
          })
        })
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({ center: [0, 0], zoom: 1 })
});
```

Comment: Thank you dube ! That's what I waited for or something like this. I have only one question yet. What do you think? Can I convert a whole country into a geojson file? From a pbf(150 mb) or a large OSM file (3GB) :D ? Or from a mapsforge file? Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is possible by using VectorTile, which only loads fragments of the overall map data. However, you would have to split your source into _tiles_ first so that it can load these tiles. These tiles are also depending on the zoom level, so it's no easy task

Comment: `source: new ol.source.OSM()` is an on line map. The sense of the original question is how to replace that online map by a .pbf off line map. I can locate a pbf in the public dir

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example) of hosting vector tiles in offline mode.  It shows how to:

- Extract the raw PBF files from an mbtile package, in the standard tiles map folder structure
- Access them using the MapBoxGL client library.  OpenLayers should work in a similar fashion

Only thing I'm not sure of is whether the browser will allow local access to the PBF files.